# What's different about my bed in the College of Winterhold?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I sleep at my home in Whiterun, or in a purchased bed at an inn, I get the Well Rested buff.(10% to skill increases)

When I sleep in a bed out in the wilderness I only get a Rested Buff.(5% to skill increases)

When I sleep in either of my beds at the College of Winterhold, the Apprentice Bed OR the Arch-Mage Bed, I only get the Rested Buff.

I would assume that since I own the beds at the college and not the beds in the wilderness, that the buffs from them would be different. What determines which buff I get?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Rested

*5% skilling bonus for 8 hours.*

- Beds in the wild.
- **Owned beds you were given permission to use.**

### Well Rested

*10% skilling bonus for 8 hours.*

- Rented beds.
- Own beds.

### Lover's Comfort

*15% skilling bonus for 8 hours*

- Beds in the house your spouse resides.

Comment: But the beds in the college should be considered “own”, no?

Comment: @svick : I would think so, but since I never 'bought' the college, I can see why it would fall under the 'permission' category.

Comment: @svick You only get to sleep there because you passed the test to become a student. The bed doesn't really belong to you.

Comment: @Renan And the Archmage's bed?

Comment: @Renan : The apprentice bed doesn't, but I certainly feel that the Arch-Mage bed does. I'm the Arch-Mage.

Comment: @Izsi The College of Winterhold can be compared to any other college. The facilities in the principal's room doesn't belong to him but are there at his disposal. Should another person take the title, you will no longer be allowed in the room.

Answer (score -3):

when you sleep in bed in wilderness you get 5% bonus.
when you sleep in normal bed (a bed you own) you get 10% bonus.
when you sleep in a normal bed with your spouse you get 15% bonus.

Comment: What about the beds I own at the college? That was kinda the point of the question.