# Is there a way to get a free house in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I love to play Skyrim, but I am broke. I can't seem to get enough money for the cheapest one I know of, the one In Whiterun. Does anyone know of a cheaper one or a way I can get a free one?

Comment: any reason in particular you want a house?  is it for a bed or to store stuff

Comment: If you aren't above using the [enchanting loop](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:Skyrim:Alchemy/Enchanting_Loop), you could earn enough money instantly.

Answer (score 7):

SPOILERS AS FOLLOWS

The only one I can think of is the ArchMage Hall in the College of Winterhold. It is free (you must complete a quest line to get it though), but it is not really a house, more of a huge room, many chests, an ingredient garden (alchemy)  a bed, and lots of loot and potions. It also has an alchemy table and an enchanting table (plus lots of soul gems). It has the same setting of a house, and is even bigger/better than most.

Also, it does not require any DLC to obtain it.

Comment: actually there are a few other dwellings you can get for free, such as the *spoilers* dawnstar DB sanctuary

Comment: Doesn't that one need dlc? I am trying to mainly list non-dlc ones because there are many people who don't use it.

Comment: nope, dark brotherhood is vanilla skyrim.  Though to be fair, you probably thought I was talking about dragonborn

Comment: i thought you meant the vampire DLC

Comment: This dwelling is  somewhat not as good as a house for resting, the room (and bed inside)is ['loaned'](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51552/whats-different-about-my-bed-in-the-college-of-winterhold) which isn't as a good for resting bonuses as a bed you own.

Answer (score 7):

You can get a free house in [Solstheim](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Served_Cold) if you have Dragonborn installed and you stop an assassination.

You could squat in the [Abandoned_House](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Abandoned_House) or one of the other [safe places](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Category:Skyrim-Places-Safe).

Answer (score 4):

There is a glitch that allow you to get a house in town for free when becoming Thane:

1. Talk to the steward about the house, say yes and then quickly go to the nearest container and place all of your gold before the steward finishes the dialogue.
2. You should get the book and key, now take the gold back from the container. NOTE: In all the city palaces, make sure to find the nearest container and use Slow Time shout if you need help.

Here are some near containers in Cities

Markarth: Dwarven chest next to the steward.

Solitude: Cupboard next to Falk.

Whiterun: Drawers in the courtroom [Use Slow Time or Whirlwind Sprint], chest in the maproom, and other containers in steward's bedroom.

Windhelm: Containers in kitchen [Use Slow Time or Whirlwind Sprint].

Riften: Chests left and right of the court.

Comment: I'm confused, your profile for the edit is "Jim" and the answerer is "Jim", are these your same accounts? If so, you know that SE can merge accounts for you.

Comment: @r3tr0t3hPeNgU1NoFd00m it's just that the user who answered this question is actually me, but then it got signed out and I had to create a new profile.

Comment: My new profile is the white one, my previous is the yellow one, @r3tr0t3hPeNgU1NoFd00m. Sorry if it confuses you if I merge accounts but I should have change the name better. Besides there are other users who're named Jim too.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, you can wait and collect 5000 septims. Talk to the steward to buy a home, and after confirming, quickly exit while he is still speaking and store all your money in the closest chest, barrel or cupboard. When the steward has finished to speak, the game will try take you 5000, but he can't because you don't have them. You can still get the key and enter the house.

Comment: This does require you to have the money up front, however, so doesn't answer the original question

Answer (score 2):

There are some free houses in the game, but you need to complete certain guild questline to get a free house.

> College of Winterhold: Arch Mage's Quarters.
>  Dark Brotherhood: Dawnstar Sanctuary.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to, but not the same as, the Arch Mage's Quarters mentioned in a couple answers already. For that you have to go through an entire quest line.

If you merely start the College quest line(gain access to the college), you get a cubicle in the Hall of Attainment with a bed and a number of safe storage containers excluding the barrels. Across the way in the Hall of Countenance you can find both an alchemy lab with lots of free ingredients and an arcane enchanter with a number of free soul gems both empty and full.

Answer (score 0):

I just befriended Uthgerd the Unbroken and she became my companion and gave me her house key. Even if she dies you get to keep the house and store all your stuff in. It's in Whiterun.

Answer (score -1):

Mistwatch, although you don't own the bed. It's not too far of a walk from Whiterun either

Answer (score -2):

There is one more place but it is out of the way but if you go to labrynthian and go to the wooden mask and put it on in the place you found it all the containers are safe